# Choose entry from a list (creating users)

Tags: ansible

First thing first - I'm not an Ansible wiz and I guess there is a better way to do this, but this is how I managed to do this. 
I needed to create users on Linux servers, I used this to read the users parameters from a file and create all by using 'with_items'.

This worked perfectly.

I wanted to add an option to create only one user from the list.

This is my yml script:

```
---
- hosts: all
  user: deploy
  become: yes

  tasks:
  - include_vars: ../variables/users.yml
    #  - command: echo {{ Guser }}
  - debug: msg={{ users }}

  - name: Create DevOps team users
    user: name={{ item.username }} shell=/bin/bash createhome=yes comment='Created by Ansi' groups={{ item.use_sudo }} uid={{ item.use_uid }} group={{ item.use_group }} state=present
    ignore_errors: yes
    with_items:
      - '{{ Guser }}'
    when: Guser is defined
```

And this is how I run it:

```
ansible-playbook --extra-vars "Guser=gilil2" -l myserver /home/devops/roles/create-users/tasks/create_user_by_name.yml -u deploy
```

Snip from my variables/users.yml

```
---
users:
  - username: gilil
    use_sudo:
    use_uid: 2005
    use_group: users

  - username: gilil2
    use_sudo:
    use_uid: 1010
    use_group: users

  - username: gilil3
    use_sudo:
    use_uid: 1011
    use_group: users
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `selectattr` Jinja2 filter:

```
  - name: Create DevOps team users
    user: name={{ item.username }} shell=/bin/bash createhome=yes comment='Created by Ansi' groups={{ item.use_sudo }} uid={{ item.use_uid }} group={{ item.use_group }} state=present
    ignore_errors: yes
    with_items: "{{ users | selectattr('username','equalto',Guser|default('uknown')) | list }}"
```

This will reduce original `users` list to a list of elements where `username` attribute equals to `Guser` vars' value or `unknown` if `Guser` is undefined. I assume that there are no user with `uknown` username, so `selectattr` can generate empty list in this case.